# Disable field or button if user exceeds number of tries

Tags: usability, design-patterns

I'm currently facing this design issue:
When a user exceeds the number of attempts given to fill up a verification code field, he or she will not be able to try again until 20min later. If within this period, he attempts again, it resets the clock.

I'm thinking of disabling the button during the 20min to prevent the user from submitting an input. Have this design pattern been used before? I'm wondering what the drawbacks are for this.

Comment: + Warn them they are going to get locked out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, disabling the button is the right call.
Letting the user submit something within the 20 min period and reseting the duration is strange and confusing. The user is punished for trying basically.

You could also add message that lets the users know that the submission will be disabled for 20 min if they input a # of incorrect codes.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is pretty much analogous to all other scenarios that the 'disable' feature of buttons (and clickable widgets) was designed for. What would be crucial in your case is that the backend/recipient system enforces the 20minute rule even when requests do come through. Also what is to stop your user opening another browser window/clearing session and reattempting sooner than 20 minutes?